# Найти сумму первых n чисел Фибоначчи

Tags: java

Задание: для натурального числа n (в данном случае это 8 и 11) найти значение результата равного первым n чисел Фибоначчи.
Я пытался сделать по такому коду, но оно вместо этого выводит 32 и 143. Второй результат правильный но первый почему-то нет:

```
    int n0 = 0;
    int n1 = 1;
    int n2 = 1;
    int result = n;

for(int i=2; i<n; i++) {
    result = n1 + n0 + n1;
    n0 = n1;
    n1= n2;
    n2 = result+1;
}


    return result;
```

Comment: Какой результат ожидается? Ну и выведи свои числа на экран, увидишь, что они совсем не числа Фиббоначчи.

Answer (score 1):

Как известно, сумма *N* чисел Фибоначчи от F(1) до F(N) равна [*F(N + 2) - 1*](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B0_%D0%A4%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D1%87%D0%B8#%D0%A2%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0), поэтому для её вычисления достаточно вызвать метод для вычисления обычного числа Фибоначчи.

```java
public static long sumF(long n) {
    return fib(n + 2) - 1; // или fibRec(n + 2) - 1
}

// рекурсивное вычисление
public static long fibRec(long n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    return fibRec(n - 1) + fibRec(n - 2);
}

// итеративное вычисление
public static long fib(long n) {
    if (n < 2) return n;
    long a = 0, b = 1, f = 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++) {
        f = a + b;
        a = b;
        b = f;
    }
    return f;
}
```

Тест:

```java
System.out.println(sumFib(8));  // -> 54 
System.out.println(sumFib(11)); // -> 232
```

---

Для вычисления суммы N чисел, начиная с F(0) = 0, достаточно изменить формулу на `F(N + 1) - 1`:

```java
public static long sumFfrom0(long n) {
    return fib(n + 1) - 1; // или fibRec(n + 1) - 1
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Давайте посчитаем сумму первых чисел Фибоначчи.

У ряда есть два варианта, оба встречаются часто, поэтому мы можем выбрать любой. Первый ряд начинается с 0, 1, 1, 2...; второй — с 1, 1, 2, 3...

Пусть у нас будет первый ряд.

| n | Fib(n) | Sum(Fib(n)) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0 | 0 |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 | 4 |
| 4 | 3 | 7 |
| 5 | 5 | 12 |
| 6 | 8 | 20 |
| 7 | 13 | 33 |
| 8 | 21 | 54 |
| 9 | 34 | 88 |

Мы видим формулу, про которую сказано в соседнем ответе: `Sum(Fib(n)) = Fib(n + 2) - 1`. Я заинтересовался, откуда это *известно*.

Мне показалось что её легко вывести по индукции.

Предположим, что `Sum(Fib(n)) = Fib(n + 2) - 1` для какого то `n`.

Тогда `Sum(Fib(n + 1)) = Sum(Fib(n)) + Fib(n + 1)`. Если верно первое равенство, то второе равенство равно `Fib(n + 2) - 1 + Fib(n + 1)`. Но `Fib(n + 1) + Fib(n + 2) = Fib(n + 3)`, следовательно, второе равенство это `Fin(n + 3) - 1`. Следовательно, `Sum(Fib(n + 1)) = Fib(n + 3) - 1`. Обозначив `n + 1 = m`, можем записать его как `Sum(Fib(m)) = Fib(m + 2) - 1`.

Шаг индукции мы доказали. Убедимся, что `Sum(Fib(n)) = Fib(n + 2) - 1` для `n = 0, 1, 2, 3...` Из таблицы выдим, что это так.

Так что да, простейший способ это формула, доказанная по индукции. Либо можете посчитать сумму вручную:

```java
public class MyClass {
    static final int N = 9;
    
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int a = 0;
        int b = 1;
        int sum = a + b;
        for (int i = 2; i <= N; i++) {
            int t = a;
            a = b;
            b = t + b;
            sum += b;
        }
        
        System.out.format("Sum(Fib(%d)) = %d", N, sum); // => 88
    }
}
```

Всё, как в таблице.

Comment: У вас тоже в индексе смещение на 1: F(0) = 0, т.е. в таблице колонка _n_ должна начинаться с 0.

Comment: @NowhereMan вы не путаете между "найти сумму N первых числе ряда" и "найти сумму от Fib0 до FibN" ?

Comment: @NowhereMan, переписал, теперь n начинается в 0.

Answer (score -1):

Имхо, проще пробежаться по числам Фибоначчи и вычислить их сумму. Пример на C#

```
int getFibSum(int n)
{
    if (n == 1) return 0;
    if (n == 2) return 1;

    int n1 = 0;
    int n2 = 1;
    int ret = 1;

    for (int i = 3; i <= n; i++)
    {
        var n3 = n1 + n2;
        ret += n3;
        n1 = n2;
        n2 = n3;
    }

    return ret;
}
```

Проверка

```
Console.WriteLine(getFibSum(8));
Console.WriteLine(getFibSum(11));
```

Вывод

```
33
143
```

Comment: Смещение на 1 получилось, _F₀ = 0, F₁ = 1, F₂ = 1, F₃ = 2,... F₈ = 21_, и сумма первых _8_ чисел Фибоначчи не может быть 33.

Comment: это если считать числа Фибоначчи от нуля (F0) =) Я считаю от одного, то есть `0+1+1+2+3+5+8+13 = 33` - сумма первых 8 элементов ряда

Comment: Я пользовался формулой из википедии, в которой F0 отбрасывается, и N чисел считаются от F1 до Fn; у вас фактически выходит от F0 до Fn-1

Comment: Так и задумано, я ведь первые 8 элементов складываю